# Use Hibernate Criteria to fetch same Objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two objects.One is Company,the other is Country.The Company object has some properties,and two of them relate with the Country object,which called "controllerCountry" and "registCountry".When I use Hibernate Criteria to get Companies,have a n+1-query(not really) problem.

My Company object code:

```
public class Company implements Serializable{

private Country controllerCountryArea;

private Country registCountryArea;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Country.class,optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="controller_country",referencedColumnName="code",insertable=false,updatable=false)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
public Country getControllerCountryArea() {
    return controllerCountryArea;
}

public void setControllerCountryArea(Country controllerCountryArea) {
    this.controllerCountryArea = controllerCountryArea;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Country.class,optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="regist_country",referencedColumnName="code",insertable=false,upda         table=false)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)
public Country getRegistCountryArea() {
    return registCountryArea;
}

public void setRegistCountryArea(Country registCountryArea) {
    this.registCountryArea = registCountryArea;
}
}
```

My Country object code:

```
public class Country implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3070416090656703733L;

private Integer id;
private String code;
private String numcode;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="CODE")
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

@Column(name="NUMCODE")
public String getNumcode() {
    return numcode;
}

public void setNumcode(String numcode) {
    this.numcode = numcode;
}
}
```

My Query code:

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(Company.class);
List list = criteria.list()
```

I get the select SQL from console:

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id14_2_, this_.controller_country as controller10_14_2_, this_.regist_country as regist28_14_2_,  countryare2_.id as id4_0_, countryare2_.CODE as CODE4_0_,  countryare2_.NUMCODE as NUMCODE4_0_, countryare3_.id as id4_1_, countryare3_.CODE as CODE4_1_,  countryare3_.NUMCODE as NUMCODE4_1_ from ps_ctf_company this_ left outer join PS_CTF_DICT_country countryare2_ on this_.controller_country=countryare2_.CODE left outer join PS_CTF_DICT_country countryare3_ on this_.regist_country=countryare3_.CODE order by this_.code asc
Hibernate: select countryare0_.id as id4_0_, countryare0_.CODE as CODE4_0_, countryare0_.NUMCODE as NUMCODE4_0_ from PS_CTF_DICT_country countryare0_ where countryare0_.CODE=?
Hibernate: select countryare0_.id as id4_0_, countryare0_.CODE as CODE4_0_, countryare0_.NUMCODE as NUMCODE4_0_ from PS_CTF_DICT_country countryare0_ where countryare0_.CODE=?
Hibernate: select countryare0_.id as id4_0_, countryare0_.CODE as CODE4_0_, countryare0_.NUMCODE as NUMCODE4_0_ from PS_CTF_DICT_country countryare0_ where countryare0_.CODE=?
Hibernate: select countryare0_.id as id4_0_, countryare0_.CODE as CODE4_0_, countryare0_.NUMCODE as NUMCODE4_0_ from PS_CTF_DICT_country countryare0_ where countryare0_.CODE=?
Hibernate: select countryare0_.id as id4_0_, countryare0_.CODE as CODE4_0_, countryare0_.NUMCODE as NUMCODE4_0_ from PS_CTF_DICT_country countryare0_ where countryare0_.CODE=?
```

In fact,the first sql is what I want,and it get 5 results as expected(ues 'left join' get the 'controllerCountry' and 'registCountry').I can't understand why there are other 5 sql. If the problem is n+1-query,there should be other 10 sql(5 sql for select 'controllerCountry' and the other for select 'registCountry').Can anybody tell me what happened and how can I get the results by just one sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is eager loading which you can do with following:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Country.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="controller_country",referencedColumnName="code",insertable=false,updatable=false)
public Country getControllerCountryArea() {
    return controllerCountryArea;
}
```

And same for the other collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in first query `JOIN` is executed for criteria and optional matching in `WHERE` clause. You have to direct `Criteria` to fetch children right away. You can do that by. As for the future, here is nice piece of [Hibernate's documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/)

```
criteria.setFetchMode("name_of_property_to_fetch", FetchMode.EAGER);
```